# Exit C function cleanly

Tags: c, function, return

I have a couple of functions. Basically a menu where a user can choose 1-n different options, and each of those options have a function associated with them. In this example it's been dumbed down.

What I am trying to determine is the best way to exit a function prematurely. For example, when the user presses enter whilst in the function of a menu option, I want the program to send them back to the menu without running anything else in that function.

In the case below, I simply call `showMenu()` and place a `return` statement after it. The only thing is, if the user quits multiple functions there will be a trail of return statements that needs to be unraveled at the end.

Could somebody please show me if there is a more efficient way to achieve this or whether I am on the money.

```
void showMenu()
{
   //Display menu

   //Prompt user for menu option

   //Run function of appropriate menu option
   runSelectedFunction();
} 

void runSelectedFunction()
{
   //Get user input for the function and validate

   //Check if the user input was only a '\n' if so show the menu and exit
   showMenu();
   return;

   //Do the stuff that this function is meant to do.
}
```

Comment: Single entry, single exit makes a program much easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good to me. Or - since there are many around that are against having multiple exit points form a single function - you could do:

```
void func()
{
   //get input

   if ( checkMenu() )
   {
      //do the stuff I am meant to do
   }
   else
   { 
      showMenu();
   }
}
```

so you are avoiding adding a second return to your function. Also you could have the `showMenu()` call always at the end of the function, depending on your needs

hth

Mario

Answer (score 0):

The best way? In short, don't.

Why?

Although there's nothing technically wrong with it and you'll find it *all* over the place, it can sometimes lead to headaches when trying to track down bugs or memory leaks in complex code.

Use early returns only when absolutely necessary and even then try to find an alternative first :)

Comment: How would you recommend solving the problem of returning to the menu once the user presses enter?

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing a whole lot more about the program. However, I might implement a form of an observer design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), construct an event object when the user presses enter (maybe different objects on other events) and then dispatch it just before the function returns.

Comment: A bit more complicated than I need for this application, but definitely something I will look into understanding. Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for something simple, then Mario's answer is just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the following pattern to ensure your function always returns from one place, giving you the opportunity to always free resources (or report errors, etc):

```
int func(void)
{
    int ret = 0;

    do
    {
        if (!allocate_resource())
        {
            ret = -1;
            break;
        }

        if (!allocate_more_resources())
        {
            ret = -2;
            break;
        }

        do_stuff();
    }
    while (0);

    free_allocated_resources();

    return (ret);
}
```